# Selecionar 2 tabelas relacionadas e 1 não relacionada em um query

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho essa consulta a baixo que me retorna dados de duas tabelas relacionadas.
Ela pega todos os campos de veículo e todos campos de produtos com "id_transfer" iguais

```
 $cmd = "SELECT p.*, v.* FROM produtos AS p
       INNER JOIN veiculos AS v
       ON p.id_veiculo= v.id_veiculo where p.id_transfer = '$id_transfer' AND     
 v.id_transfer = '$id_transfer' AND  nome LIKE '%$pesq%' ORDER by nome limit 
 $inicio,$registros
```

Não estou sabendo como inserir uma 3ª tabela que não precisa ser relacionada.

Seria assim:

```
  Selecione 
  todos tabala veiculo
  todos tabela produtos
  com seu id_tranfer iguais
  e selecione 
  todos da tabela agenda_saidas
  com status iguais ativo

  Produto
  +--------+----------------+---------------+
  |   id   |     Destino    |    Data       |
  +--------+----------------+---------------+
  |  01    | Rio de Janeiro | 01/01/2015    |
  |  02    | São Paulo      | 01/01/2015    |
  +--------+----------------+---------------+
  Veiculo
  +--------+----------------+---------------+
  |   id   |     Veiculo    |    Cor        |
  +--------+----------------+---------------+
  |  01    |     Palio      |   Preto       |
  |  02    |     GOL        |   Branco      |
  +--------+----------------+---------------+

  agenda_saidas
  +--------+----------------+---------------+
  |   x1   |      x2        |    x3         |
  +--------+----------------+---------------+
  |   xxx  |      xxx       |    xxx        |
  |   xxx  |      xxx       |    xxx        |
  +--------+----------------+---------------+

   while{ 
   Resultado = Rio de Janeiro 01/01/2015 Palio Preto
   Resultado = São Paulo 01/01/2015 GOL Branco
   .....
   Resultado = xxx xxx xxx  
   Resultado = xxx xxx xxx    
   .....
   Se é que isso e possível..
   }
```

Comment: Não estou com tempo de testar algo agora, mas em mente no momento pode fazer um inner join da tabela agenda_saidas e um group by agenda_saidas.id (pois ele irá fazer cruzamento nXm).

Comment: Exatamente como o @LuisHenrique falou, utilize um Join, `"SELECT p.*, v.* FROM produtos AS p INNER JOIN veiculos AS v ON p.id_veiculo= v.id_veiculo where p.id_transfer = '$id_transfer' AND v.id_transfer = '$id_transfer' AND  nome LIKE '%$pesq%' JOIN agenda_saidas WHERE status = 'ativo' ORDER by nome limit  $inicio,$registros` (Não testei, mas também não sei se o resultado será o esperado).

Comment: Qual a relação da tabela *agenda_saidas* com os registros que você quer recuperar?

Comment: Não funcionou.. erroo boolean given in /home/mrangelc/public_html/transfer.php on line 382
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/mrangelc/public_html/files/transfer.php on line 384

Answer (score 1):

Essa consulta relacionara todos produtos/veiculos com todas as agenda_saidas

```
SELECT p.*, v.*, ags.*
FROM produtos AS p
JOIN veiculos AS v ON p.id_veiculo = v.id_veiculo and v.id_transfer = p.id_transfer
JOIN agenda_saidas ags ON ags.status = 'ativo'
where p.id_transfer = '$id_transfer' AND  nome LIKE '%$pesq%' 
ORDER by nome 
limit $inicio,$registros
```

o que me parece o que você quer é todos produtos/veiculos + agenda_saidas. Nesse caso você precisa saber exatamente qual colunas você quer. São duas consultas diferentes, mas ambas necessitam ter o mesmo numero de colunas.

```
select * from (
    SELECT p.Destino as nome, p.Data as data, v.Veiculo, v.Cor
    FROM produtos AS p
    JOIN veiculos AS v ON p.id_veiculo = v.id_veiculo and v.id_transfer = p.id_transfer
    where p.id_transfer = '$id_transfer' AND  nome LIKE '%$pesq%' 
    UNION
    SELECT ags.x1, ags.x2, ags.x3, '' 
    FROM agenda_saidas ags 
    WHERE ags.status = 'ativo'
    ) produtos_veiculos_agenda_saidas
    ORDER by nome 
limit $inicio,$registros
```

verifique o nome das colunas, não sei se você postou no nome correto das tabelas e colunas.

Comment: Só á relacionamento entre a tabela veiculo e produto a tabela agenda_saida não tem relacionamento nenhum

Comment: eu entendi isso, eu não entendi qual é o resultado final. vc quer p.*, v.*, ags.* (primeira query)? ou p/v + ags( segunda query)?

Comment: eu quero p.*, v.* na primeira query e ags* na segunda.

Comment: então, foi o que foi postado, eu postei duas query, a segunda é a que você quer, mas elas precisam ter o mesmo numero de colunas, se é diferente você faz no php duas consultas diferentes

Comment: mais as colunas precisam ser iguais ou só tem que ter o mesmo numero?

Comment: só o mesmo número de colunas, como vc pode ver na segunda consulta interna da segunda query. Tem uma coluna em branco só para terem o mesmo número

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer um JOIN na tabela `agenda_saidas` sem específicar condição de junção, uma vez que a tabela não tem relação.

Porém isso irá causar um cruzamento n x m (todas as linhas com todas as linhas), ou seja, vai duplicar os resultador de veículos e produtos para cada instância que exista na tabela `agenda_saidas`.

Pode resolver isso, fazendo um `group by` por veículo.

```
SELECT Veiculo.*, Produto.*, agenda_saidas.* FROM Veiculo
INNER JOIN Produto ON Produto.veiculo_id = Veiculo.id
INNER JOIN agenda_saidas
WHERE Veiculo.transfer_id = 1 AND Produto.transfer_id = 1
GROUP BY Veiculo.id
```

Veja funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9607/2).

Não sei se é exatamente isto que você quer, me baseei nos trechos de códigos da pergunta. Se precisar de mais alguma coisa, sugiro uma edição em sua pergunta.